# Can anyone help with identifying this tree?

Tags: uk, trees, plants, tree-identification

The tree kind of resembles an ash but has green buds, there are pinnate leaflets with rounded tips

[image: bark]

close up of leaflets

[image: leaflets]

### edit

This tree is located in Cambidgeshire in the United Kingdom

Comment: I'll consult the resident botanist and see what she says.

Comment: Young Manna Ash?

Comment: @ShemSeger again it looks close, I'm sure this is some kind of ash, this was missing the points on the end of the leaves

Comment: The younger greener leaves in the top picture seem to still have the points, but the leaves in the bottom picture look like they've lost their points somehow, as if they were plucked off. It looks like there's brown scarring on the leaf tips where it used to be. Could just be old, end of season leaves that have been beaten in the wind.

Comment: @ShemSeger I'm only beginning to learn about trees so can't comment too much - I think you may be right, if you want to add an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: I'm only guessing, I'll let someone else who knows what they're talking about post an answer.

Comment: @ChrisJ -- Identification is not possible with these pictures alone.  Do you have any that are zoomed out farther?  One of the key identification criteria is the arrangement of the branches.

Comment: @RussellSteen I'll try and get another one next time I'm out that way, today or tomorrow

Comment: At first sight it looks like the walnut trees we have here (Romania). Are there some fruits/remains under it? Did you try to crush the leaves and smell them? Walnut leaves have a strong, typical smell...

Comment: @Akabelle oooh it does look a lot like a walnut tree, I'll check

Comment: @ChrisJ did it produce some fruits this year? :)

Answer (score 6):

I would say it is a walnut tree. The bole is flat, and at first sight it seems that someone cut the lower branches of it (at some point when the tree was younger). The leaves also look like the ones of walnut.

If it has no fruits on the branches then it might be a bad year, or some hail destroyed the harvest, or the tree might have some illness (see points on the lower leaves).

Disclaimer: I am not a botanist, we just have a lot of walnut trees in our orchard.

Comment: Even in a bad year there would be evidence of nuts on the ground from previous years. A quick look should confirm this. Personally, I think your correct as we have many walnut trees here too.

Comment: @Chris J, did the tree have some nuts last year? :)